# Integer/decimal user input: how to serialize/store the value

Tags: javascript, ruby, postgresql, graphql, apollo

Our stack is currently: React SPA/Apollo/GraphQL/Rails/PostgreSQL.

We have a web form with a number input that maybe (or not) be used to entry decimal values (dynamic/user-created form).

We want the form to be lenient (it has an autosave feature). If user types `,3` or `17,`, that is considered a valid number value. But not too lenient, the number should by parseable as a float and be able to display in graphs...

Also, when the user visit the form again, we want to make sure to init the number input with the exact same value he typed initially (I mean, `,3` does not become magically `0,3`)

I'd like to know, for our stack, how to serialize (sending as GraphQL payload) and store (in PostgreSQL) and manipulate (in JS/Ruby) such number without loosing the initial user input value.

---

I'm thinking it would be simpler to send/store a string, as long as it's validated that it can be parsed.

Just wondering if there is a "proper" solution, for example using number libs, custom GraphQL scalar type, decimal SQL type... that seems complicated to me, anyone did something similar before?

Comment: I've done it and it's great. String is a solid way of sending numbers between the client and server, especially since JS floats can't represent Decimals and will have floating point arithmetic problems. Each client (front end, server, etc) should be able to read a string number from a request and convert it to whatever lib/parser format that they are using. You would want to filter special characters like , . $ % away and send only from the set `0123456789` so every part of your architecture can understand it without reformatting.

Answer (score 1):

Create two fields. One for user input and other with parsed value. I do not think this will be different for any stack.

The challenge is how to show to a user how you understood entered value. This could be solved with a hint with a parsed value under the text field.

Answer (score 1):

you should choose type of the input as "text" instead of number, so you can create a specific format for your input. first, add a property to your state

```
state={amount:""}
```

input section for amount in your form should be like this:

```
<input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Amount"
            value={this.state.amount}
            onChange={this.onAmountChange}
          />



onAmountChange = e => {
    const amount = e.target.value;
    if (!amount || amount.match(/^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$/)) {
      this.setState(() => ({ amount }));
    }
  };
```

regexp in above function means start with any number with optional -, and optionally u can end with 2 decimal number. you can change it for your form.

if you want to add only positive numbers if your form is for price you can use this regexp:

```
amount.match(/^\d{1,}(\.\d{0,2})?$/)
```